# g++ unrecognized debug output level 'db' error while compiling

Tags: makefile, gdb, g++

I am trying to use some open source program, and I typed 'make data' to create 'data' file, but it created following response with error

```
<stdin>:3:6: warning: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘main’ with no type [-Wreturn-type]  
mpicxx -o data data.o -l/home/songyi719/Desktop/Research/petsc-3.1-p6/installation_folder/include -l/usr/include -l/home/songyi719/Desktop/Research/petsc-3.1-p6/installation_folder/include -g -gdb -MMD -MP -L//lib -L/home/songyi719/Desktop/Research/petsc-3.1-p6/installation_folder/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/home/songyi719/Desktop/Research/petsc-3.1-p6/installation_folder/lib -L./ -lpthread -lrt -lstdc++ -lX11 -lpetsc -lHYPRE -lblas -llapack -lgfortran -g -ldl  
g++: error: unrecognized debug output level ‘db’  
make: *** [makefile:128: data] Error 1
```

and corresponding part at 'makefile' about data is

```
data: tests tecplottest data.o  
$(LIBFLAG) $(LIBTECPLOT)
    $(MPICXX) -o data data.o -l$(PETSCINC) -l$(TECINC) -l$(HYPREINC) -g -gdb -MMD -MP $(LIBDIR) $(LIBFLAG) $(LIBTECPLOT)
```

I guess that this error may have been caused because g++ compiler recognized 'gdb' in wrong way, but I couldn't know why and how to solve this problem

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-gdb` is not a valid GCC argument, and that is exactly what the error tells you.

Use `-ggdb` instead.

**Update:**

> `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/songyi719/Desktop/Research/petsc-3.1-p6/installation_folder/include`

Did you write the `Makefile` yourself?

This is wrong: `... -l$(PETSCINC) -l$(TECINC) -l$(HYPREINC) ...`

All of these `-l`s should be `-I`s instead: `... -I$(PETSCINC) -I$(TECINC) -I$(HYPREINC) ...`

**Update2:**

Actually, since this is a link command and there are no sources being complied here, all of these: `-I$(PETSCINC) -I$(TECINC) -I$(HYPREINC)` should be deleted instead (just from the link command).

Comment: Thanks! error is gone! However, it returns new message

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/songyi719/Desktop/Research/petsc-3.1-p6/installation_folder/include  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/include  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/songyi719/Desktop/Research/petsc-3.1-p6/installation_folder/include  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
make: *** [makefile:128: data] Error 1  

How can it be fixed?

Comment: @songyi719 I've updated the answer again with an even better fix.